# Problem using string conditional with np.select

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to create a new column in a pandas dataframe based on whether a string is contained in another column. I'm using np.select based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913659/pandas-conditional-creation-of-a-series-dataframe-column). Here is an example dataframe and an example function to create the new column

```py
df=pd.DataFrame({'column':['one','ones','other','two','twos','others','three','threes']})

def add(df):

    conditions = [
        ('one' in df['column']),
        ('two' in df['column']),
        ('three' in df['column']),
        ('other' in df['column'])] 

    choices = [1, 2, 3, 0]
    df['Int'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=0)

    return df

new_df=add(df)
```

The output I'm getting is

```py
   column  Int
0     one    0
1    ones    0
2   other    0
3     two    0
4    twos    0
5  others    0
6   three    0
7  threes    0
```

And what I want is

```py
   column  Int
0     one    1
1    ones    1
2   other    0
3     two    2
4    twos    2
5  others    0
6   three    3
7  threes    3
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If need test substrings use [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
 conditions = [
        (df['column'].str.contains('one')),
        (df['column'].str.contains('two')),
        (df['column'].str.contains('three')),
        (df['column'].str.contains('other'))]
```

If need exact match use [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) or `==`:

```
 conditions = [
        (df['column'].eq('one')),
        (df['column'].eq('two')),
        (df['column'].eq('three')),
        (df['column'].eq('other'))]
```

---

```
 conditions = [
        (df['column'] == 'one'),
        (df['column'] == 'two'),
        (df['column'] == 'three'),
        (df['column'] == 'other')]
```

---

```
print (new_df)
   column  Int
0     one    1
1    ones    1
2   other    0
3     two    2
4    twos    2
5  others    0
6   three    3
7  threes    3
```

Comment: I am facing the similar issue, can you take a look here, please? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63642173/pandas-apply-merge-operations-from-a-column